# GWT Garbage collection of cyclical assignments/links

Tags: java, gwt, garbage-collection, linked-list

I am presuming that GWT manages garbage collection, and is capable of preventing the buildup of a memory sink (aka leak), when a widget or variable is no longer referenced anywhere anymore within the application.

So setting a reference/variable to null is insufficient because that widget/object might be referenced/linked by somewhere else in the app. Especially in Trees where I hash up the information associated with the treeitems.

If anyone has objections to the above presumptions, do please speak your mind.

All right, what about the case where a cluster of objects are referencing each other but on the whole there is no reference chain that can trace them to any actively used objects/variables.

A simple case is a doubly link list, instantiated from my own doubly linked list class. Or a circular list instantiated also from a class I wrote myself. What if that doubly linked list or circular list is no longer referenced by any active components/objects/variables.

Does GWT gc know how to collect and destroy those lists?

IF not, what precautions or design patterns I should adhere to avoid accumulation of a memory sink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that all garbage collection frameworks know how to deal with -- although I believe GWT depends on Javascript's GC, not its own.

If you examine [this section on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object), you will understand why the doubly linked list structure you describe will be correctly garbage collected -- essentially, the unreferenced list will not be reachable from any of the roots.